# gcloud preview app deploy returns 400 error

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

Trying to deploy some static content to GAE, since they removed the push-to-deploy pipeline feature. I've setup a brand new project. It's in the US region. Did `gcloud auth login` again. Still getting the same response.

Verbose debug output below. [REDACTED] is my addition to the code.

```
$ gcloud preview app deploy dist/app.yaml --verbosity debug
DEBUG: Running gcloud.preview.app.deploy with Namespace(__calliope_internal_deepest_parser=ArgumentParser(prog='gcloud.preview.app.deploy', usage=None, description="*(BETA)* This command is used to deploy both code and configuration to the App Engine\nserver.  As an input it takes one or more ``DEPLOYABLES'' that should be\nuploaded.  A ``DEPLOYABLE'' can be a module's .yaml file or a configuration's\n.yaml file.", version=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=False), cmd_func=<bound method Command.Run of <googlecloudsdk.calliope.backend.Command object at 0x10bf14290>>, command_path=['gcloud', 'preview', 'app', 'deploy'], deployables=['dist/app.yaml'], document=None, env_vars=None, force=False, format=None, h=None, help=None, http_timeout=None, log_http=None, markdown=None, project=None, quiet=None, remote=False, server=None, set_default=False, trace_token=None, user_output_enabled=None, verbosity='debug', version=None).
You are about to deploy the following modules:
 - [PROJECT_ID]/default/20150612t130942  From: [/Users/[ME]/Dropbox/Sites/[PROJECT_ID]/site/dist/app.yaml]
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

Updating module [default]...DEBUG: Host: appengine.google.com
DEBUG: Host: appengine.google.com
DEBUG: Getting current resource limits.
DEBUG: Send: /api/appversion/getresourcelimits, params={'version': '20150612t130942', 'app_id': '[PROJECT_ID]'}
DEBUG: _Authenticate configuring auth; needs_auth=False
DEBUG: Sending request to https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=[PROJECT_ID]&version=20150612t130942 headers={'X-appcfg-api-version': '1', 'content-length': '0', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'} body=
INFO: Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO: Refreshing access_token
DEBUG: Got response: max_file_size: 32000000
max_blob_size: 32000000
max_files_to_clone: 2000
max_total_file_size: 9223372036854775807
max_file_count: 10000

DEBUG: Using resource limits: {'max_file_size': 32000000, 'max_total_file_size': 9223372036854775807, 'max_blob_size': 32000000, 'max_files_to_clone': 2000, 'max_file_count': 10000}
INFO: Reading app configuration.
DEBUG: 
Starting update of app: [PROJECT_ID], version: 20150612t130942
DEBUG: Scanning files on local disk.
INFO: Processing file [app.yaml]
INFO: Processing file [index.html]
INFO: Processing file [views/6a0e56b1.main.html]
INFO: Processing file [views/partials/90bc29e6.case-study.html]
INFO: Processing file [views/partials/cc69dea5.home.html]
INFO: Processing file [styles/9960b040.main.css]
INFO: Processing file [scripts/8a12aff1.scripts.js]
INFO: Processing file [scripts/8e6de882.libraries.js]
DEBUG: Send: /api/appversion/create, params={'version': '20150612t130942', 'app_id': '[PROJECT_ID]', 'module': 'default'}
DEBUG: _Authenticate configuring auth; needs_auth=False
DEBUG: Sending request to https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=[PROJECT_ID]&module=default&version=20150612t130942 headers={'X-appcfg-api-version': '1', 'content-length': '633', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'} body=api_version: '1'
application: [PROJECT_ID]
auto_id_policy: default
builtins:
- default: 'on'
derived_file_type:
- python_precompiled
handlers:
- script: index.html
  secure: optional
  url: /
- secure: optional
  static_dir: styles
  url: /styles
- secure: optional
  static_dir: scripts
  url: /scripts
- secure: optional
  static_dir: views
  url: /views
- secure: optional
  static_dir: fonts
  url: /fonts
- secure: optional
  static_dir: images
  url: /images
- secure: optional
  static_dir: res
  url: /res
module: default
runtime: php
threadsafe: true
version: 20150612t130942
vm_settings:
  module_yaml_path: app.yaml

INFO: Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
INFO: Refreshing access_token
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Got http error 400.
DEBUG: Unexpected results: {'status': '400', 'alternate-protocol': '443:quic,p=1', 'content-length': '318', 'expires': 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT', 'server': 'Google Frontend', 'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'date': 'Fri, 12 Jun 2015 18:09:47 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/plain'}
Updating module [default]...done.
DEBUG: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Server responded with code [400]:
  Bad Request Unexpected HTTP status 400
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/[ME]/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 538, in Execute
    result = args.cmd_func(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/[ME]/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 1124, in Run
    result = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/[ME]/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/app_commands/deploy.py", line 119, in Run
    client.DeployModule(module, version, info.parsed, info.file)
  File "/Users/[ME]/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/appengine_client.py", line 276, in DeployModule
    return appversion.DoUpload()
  File "/Users/[ME]/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/appengine_deployments.py", line 1016, in DoUpload
    missing_files = self.Begin()
  File "/Users/[ME]/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/appengine_deployments.py", line 561, in Begin
    payload=config_copy.ToYAML())
  File "/Users/[ME]/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/util.py", line 288, in Send
    result = self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/[ME]/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/util.py", line 353, in Send
    response = self._server.Send(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/[ME]/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/external/tools/appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 269, in Send
    'Unexpected HTTP status %s' % status)
  File "/Users/[ME]/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/external/tools/appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 67, in RaiseHttpError
    raise urllib2.HTTPError(url, response_info.status, msg, response_info, stream)
RPCError: Server responded with code [400]:
  Bad Request Unexpected HTTP status 400
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Server responded with code [400]:
  Bad Request Unexpected HTTP status 400
```

Comment: I am running into the same thing, I have ran `gcloud auth login` as well as `gcloud config set project [project_id]`

Comment: Same, I have this issue as well

Answer (score 6):

You might have to set the project id again if you have disabled/removed previous application from google cloud console.

```
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

The generic issue is that the error did not have a message.
Starting in the cloud SDK release tomorrow, the reason for whatever error (billing issue, not enough quota, whatever) will be displayed, so please try to get the newer cloud SDK tomorrow.

Comment: Just an update, the [1.9.23 SDK was released today](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads), so as Ludo suggests,  OP, please test this to see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

For me I hadn't enabled billing in **Compute > Compute Engine > VM instances** on my Google Console project. It works now!

Comment: Billing seems to be setup properly on my project. That's didn't seem to affect anything... thanks anyway though, glad it worked for you.

Comment: You gotta instantiate an instance with your default payments plan and then deploy your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you have appcfg.py installed, you can run that to deploy and it will give the exact error message, I found mine to be an invalid api_version for the java runtime (to which i can't find the valid number and 1 isn't it)

Answer (score -1):

My initial deployment was fine and after I uploaded the update, it started to fail and get the same errors as you did.  I found the issue with oauth.  Logout from google and running:

```
$ gcloud auth login
```

After relogin, I was able to deploy.  No re-coding or Managed VM setting changes were done.